# What is the best way to store incremental downloaded data?

Tags: c++, stl

Inspired by [Chromium's sha1 class](http://src.chromium.org/svn/trunk/src/base/sha1.cc), I am thinking to store incrementally downloaded data using std::string

```
// pseudo-code
char buff[BUFF_SIZE];
std::string data;
do {
    size = ReadInternetFileTo(buff,BUFF_SIZE);
    data.append(buff,size);
} while (not_finished);
```

Any foreseeable problems with this method or better way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be OK, but you may want to consider rope instead of string.  It is more efficient to append to a rope, as it won't promise to keep all bytes consecutive, which will require a reallocation.

Answer (score 2):

SGI's good old [Rope](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Rope.html) seems like a great fit, if your data's large and you can use SGI's STL -- as their docs say,

> Unlike C strings, ropes are a
>   reasonable representation for very
>   long strings such as edit buffers or
>   mail messages.